# Using $skip with the SharePoint 2013 REST API

Tags: json, rest, sharepoint

Forgive me, I'm very new to using REST.

Currently I'm using SP2013 Odata `(_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<list_name>')/items?)` to get the contents of a list. The list has 199 items in it so I need to call it twice and each time ask for a different set of items. I figured I could do this by calling:

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<list_name>')/items?$skip=100&$top=100
```

each time changing however many I need to skip. The problem is this only ever returns the first 100 items. Is there something I'm doing wrong or is `$skip` broken in the OData service?

Is there a better way to iterate through REST calls, assuming this way doesn't work or isn't practical?

*I'm using the JSon protocol with the `Accept` Header equaling `application/json;odata=verbose`*

*I suppose the `$top=100` isn't really necessary*

Edit: I've looked it up more and, I'm not entirely sure of the terms here, but using `$skip` works fine if you're using the method introduced with SharePoint 2010, i.e., `_vti_bin/ListData.svc/<list_name>?$skip=100`

Actually, funny enough, the old way doesn't set a 100 item limit on returns. So skip isn't even necessary. But, if you'd like to only return a certain segment of data, you'd have to do something like:

```
_vti_bin/ListData.svc/<list_name>?$skip=x&$top=(x+y)
```

where each time through the loop you would have something like `x+=y`

*You can either use the old method which I described above, or check out my answer below for an explanation of how to do this using SP2013 OData*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Alright, I've figured it out. `$skip` isn't a command which is meant to be used at the `items?` level. It works only at the `lists?` level. But, there's a way to do this, actually much easier than what I wanted to do.

**If you just want all the data**

In the returned data, assuming the list you are calling holds more than 100 items, there will be a `__next` at `d/__next` (assuming you are using json). This `__next` (it is a double underscorce, keep that in mind. I had a few problems at first because I was trying to get `d/_next` which never returned anything) is the right URL to get the next set of items. `__next` will only ever be a value if there is another set of items available to get.

I ended up creating a `RequestURL` variable which was initially set to to original request, but was changed to `d/__next` at the end of the loop. Then the loop went and checked if the `RequestURL` was not empty before going inside the loop.

Forgive my lack of code, I'm using SharePoint Designer 2013 to make this, and the syntax isn't horribly descriptive.

**If you'd only like a small set of data**

There's probably a few situations where you would only want `x` amount of rows from your list each time you go through the loop and that's real easy to do as well.

if you just add a `$top=x` parameter to your request, the `__next` URL that comes back with the response will give you the next `x` rows from your list. Eventually when there are no rows left to return `__next` won't be returned with the response.

Comment: If I want to do previous functionality how could I achieve that? Any suggestion?

Comment: Since the $skiptoken is ID based, I urge caution when performing server side filtering and paging as well.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget that in order to use __next you need to have a

```
$skiptoken=Paged=TRUE
```

in the url as well.

Comment: While this shouldn't be its own answer, this is critical information at least on SP2013. I was frustrated why it wasn't returning any `__next` property for nearly half an hour until I spotted this.

Comment: it seems in SP2016 it's not needed. `__next` is available without it